# Eliminate render-blocking CSS in above-the-fold content - page speed insight

Tags: css, pagespeed

**Before closing this question. Please read it**

*i had tried all the solution, which is available on this website and on other.
But no one is working. Therefore i am writing a new one.*

as i have mentioned above, i had tried all but nothing working in my case or current date.

```
<head>
    <!-- unimportant nonsense -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="bogus">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- other unimportant nonsense, such as content -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</body>


2- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"></noscript>

3 - <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
```

How to get rid of it please help.

Comment: Are you sure that Google's PageSpeed haven't cached the result for this page?

Comment: yes, i had checked several times. even in incognito mode

Comment: Do you have a URL or waterfall image?  
Do you use font files?